# Post-map-repost JavaScript form handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to write JavaScript (jQuery in this case) to handle the form submission of an already existing form. I do not have a ton of control over the form itself. It's built in a third-party landing page software with limited options.

What I'm trying to accomplish: Submit the form twice. The first time with all of the original values. The second time with a few of the values remapped.

What I've come up with so far is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery("form").submit(function(e) { // fires when the original form is submitted
  
      e.preventDefault(); // stops the form submitting / refreshing
      
      // save the values for our first AJAX call
      var formData = {
        your_first_name: jQuery("#your_first_name").val(),
        your_last_name: jQuery("#your_last_name").val(),
        your_company_name: jQuery("#your_company_name").val(),
        your_work_email: jQuery("#your_work_email").val(),
        your_referrals_first_name: jQuery("#your_referrals_first_name").val(),
        your_referrals_last_name: jQuery("#your_referrals_last_name").val(),
        your_referrals_company_name: jQuery("#your_referrals_company_name").val(),
        your_referrals_email_address: jQuery("#your_referrals_email_address").val(),
        your_referrals_phone_Number: jQuery("#your_referrals_phone_number").val(),
        how_did_you_hear_about_electrics_referral_program: jQuery("#how_did_you_hear_about_electrics_referral_program").val(),
      }

      // remaps values for second AJAX call
      var repostData = {
        your_first_name: jQuery("#your_referrals_first_name").val(),
        your_last_name: jQuery("#your_referrals_last_name").val(),
        your_company_name: jQuery("#your_referrals_company_name").val(),
        your_work_email: jQuery("#your_referrals_email_address").val(),
        your_referrals_first_name: '',
        your_referrals_last_name: '',
        your_referrals_company_name: '',
        your_referrals_email_address: '',
        your_referrals_phone_Number: '',
        how_did_you_hear_about_electrics_referral_program: jQuery("#how_did_you_hear_about_electrics_referral_program").val(),
      }
      
      // submits the form with all of the original data
      jQuery.ajax ({
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          console.log("Form 1 submitted successfully!");

          // submits the form again with new data, only if the first post was successful
          jQuery.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            data: repostData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
              console.log("Form 2 submitted successfully!");
            },
            error: function (data) {
              console.log("An error has occured on form 2");
            }
          });
        },
        error: function (data) {
          console.log("An error has occured on form 1");
        }
      });

  });
});
```

And I have a JSFiddle built here with an html form built out for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/wca18ekq/

I have tried various different methods. Some with and without AJAX. I ultimately think AJAX is the right approach here since I would like to post data more than once without refreshing.

Can anyone lend a hand here?

Comment: What are you trying to do here: https://prnt.sc/0kXwGg7WYFap
If you do this: `let someVar = jQuery("#id").val("someval")` someVar will be the HTML input, not the value

Comment: You're right - not sure what I was thinking there. Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the code above. Each ajax function returns its respective error function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the workaround approach, this would require the user to allow popups, and they would need to close the tabs after, because it would set the form target to _blank, to make it submit in a tab, then submit one time, remove the fields you dont want, then submit another time

https://jsfiddle.net/04jnfytg/

```
//won't work in the fiddle, because it doesn't submit correctly to a tab
```

Comment: I added this dummy endpoint to my Fiddle and it does seem to be working. Although, the first AJAX call is still posting its error function before then posting its success function. Any idea why?

Comment: I made an edit, check my fiddle, just a curiosity what is your backend to receive this call? PHP, c#, node?

Comment: I don't have a ton of control over the backend, as the landing page is built in a builder called Unbounce, which is why I am not too sure to what URL I should be posting to. I assumed it would just default to posting to the current url it is on already.

Comment: I see... have you tested the code in my fiddle in the real file?

Comment: I believe the code is now working but unfortunately a CORS policy is blocking ajax from making a cross origin request even though it should be on the same webpage... I'd be happy to share but not publicly. Now I am looking at possible solutions without the use of AJAX? Is this even possible to submit multiple times without ajax? Could something like this work? https://jsfiddle.net/wj9k35um/

Thank you so much for your help my friend.

Comment: Did you remove the dummy URL, to test in the real file? The CORS can be configured to not allow OUTGOING calls to different domains. I also added another approach in the answer